# Login failed for user 'domain\User'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: sql-server

A domain account is failing to login to SQL as SQL Server authentication, but the user does not exist in Security

- Successful logins are connecting using ‘DOMAIN\user’ (pay attention to the casing here)
- Failure logins are connecting using ‘domain\User’ (lowercase domain, uppercase U)
- Failure occurs every 5 minutes from ‘local machine’

Message:

> Login failed for user 'domain\User'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: ]

- There are NO services that use `domain\User` as a service account
- There does not appear to be any ODBC connections on the server
- There are not any jobs that appear to be running using the domain\User account
- `DOMAIN\user` is set up using Windows Authentication, as it should
- `domain\User` DOES NOT exist as a Security login, and I can not find anything under any of the individual Database Security folders either
- `domain\User` does not exist in any of the Groups that have access to SQL
- `domain\User` and `DOMAIN\user` are not listed in any of the Administrator groups on Server

The error seems to think `domain\User` is a Windows account that is attempting to log in using SQL Server authentication, but can not be found anywhere to justify this response

Any replication does not have either accounts being used

I'm not sure where else to look. Unless there is some way another server is attempting to access this server\database while also identifying it as running from "Client: Local Machine", I'm at a loss for where to look.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? I can't tell if you expect the login to work, or if you're looking for an explanation regarding the error.

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to pass their windows username and password on a connection string; that isn't how that works.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are getting login failures every 5 minutes and you do not know what program or process is trying to use a windows login account for SQL Server authentication? And you want to find that process...yes?  If so you could always run an extended events to trap for it.  Here is an example: https://www.sqlshack.com/using-extended-events-review-sql-server-failed-logins/

Comment: "can not be found anywhere to justify this response" ...well it must be happening, the error doesn't lie. The fact the user doesn't exist / isn't set up is irrelevant. Something is **trying** to use it. And use it incorrectly, since you can't specify a windows username as a connection string option. Does the error (or logs) not give you an IP address of where the connection attempt came from or anything like that?

Comment: @AaronDietz I'm not expecting the login to work, just hoping to find where it is coming from

Comment: @ADyson that's the problem I'm running into, the error logs show it is coming from <local machine>, so it needs to be coming from somewhere on the local machine. I 'm also wondering if it is possible that the login attempt is coming from somwhere else, but SQL is seeing it being registered as an attempt on the local machine

Comment: @nckelwd you need to look again for services, jobs or applications which might be talking to SQL Server on the server where SQL is installed. In your post you've ruled out ones running under that domain account, but that's irrelevant because it could be running under any account - it's only trying to specify that account in the SQL connection string. That doesn't necessarily mean it's actually executing with that identity.

Comment: @nckelwd another random thought...linked servers? Do any other SQL servers have a link to this one? I don't know how a connection attempt would show up in the logs offhand, you'd hope it would show as coming from the relevant server...but just throwing it in as a (remote) possibility which you hadn't mentioned above. Someone could have configured the linked server incorrectly I guess. (I suppose if the instance it's coming from is on the same SQL Server then it might show up as local, too.)

Answer (score 1):

JM_'s advice was solid.

After running an Extended Event Session using this example: [Review SQL Server Failed Logins](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-extended-events-review-sql-server-failed-logins/), I was able to identify the PID of the service detail that was running.

It seems that Solarwinds or DPA is/was using the account, but attempting to login with user 'domain\User' using SQL Authentication incorrectly.

We have a suspicion that DPA was configured a long time ago incorrectly, and was eventually corrected, but the process still remains.

The details in Task Manager show 3 PIDs (SQJobEngineWorker2.exe, and 2 instances of SWJobEngineWorker2x64.exe) with the first one causing the SQL errors, now it's just a matter of figuring out why.

Thanks for the help everyone!